# Check 2 values into ENUM

Tags: java

I have this Java Enum structure:

```
public enum ResponseCodes {

    ONE("000.200.100", 100, "successfully created checkout"),
    TWO("000.200.101", 101, "failed created checkout");

    ResponseCodes(String s, int i, String s1) {
    }
}
```

When I receive `"000.200.100"` and `"successfully created checkout"` I want to get the value `100`. How this check can be implemented?

Comment: when you receive them from *where*?

Comment: Remote API response.

Comment: how do you get a enum instance from these 2 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum ResponseCodes {

    ONE("000.200.100", 100, "successfully created checkout"),
    TWO("000.200.101", 101, "failed created checkout");
    
    private String version;    
    private String text;
    private int code;
    
    ResponseCodes(String s, int i, String s1) {
        version = s;
        text = s1;
        code = i;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
private int testMethod(){
    ResponseCodes example = ResponseCodes.ONE;
    if ( example.getVersion().equals( "000.200.100" )
            && example.getText().equals( "successfully created checkout" ) ) {
        return example.getCode();
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Or get the relevant enum:

```
private ResponseCodes getResponseCode(){
    for ( ResponseCodes c : ResponseCodes.values() ) {
        if ( c.getVersion().equals( "000.200.100" )
                && c.getText().equals( "successfully created checkout" ) ) {
            return c;
        }
    }   
    return ResponseCodes.ONE; // return a default    
}
```

Or follow a different approach:

```
// change 
ONE("000.200.100", 100, "successfully created checkout"); 
// into
SUCCESSFULLY_CREATED_CHECKOUT_000_200_100(100); // and delete the String fields

//Which makes it possible to pull the int value in this way:
private int testMethod2() {
    String text = "successfully created checkout";
    String numbers = "000.200.100";
    String enumName = (text + " " + numbers).replaceAll("( )|(\\.)", "_" ).toUpperCase();
    return ResponseCodes.valueOf(enumName).getCode();
}
```

Comment: hm... `ResponseCodes.ONE` looks like you're selecting a value. I need to make a search into the ENUM.

Comment: Yes, added an example of what you want. Instead of returning the enum, you can just return its int field.

Comment: One more question: Is there a better structure/design to implement this functionality?

Comment: If you don't mind very long names such as `successfully_created_checkout_000_200_100`, you could change the enum names and pull the int value like this: `ResponseCodes.valueOf("successfully_created_checkout_000_200_100").getCode();`

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. See here: https://totalprocessing.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/integration-guide#CNPStep1 For every type of response we have a fixed vales. One more question: Can I return some default value of there is no match into the ENUM?

Comment: You could add another enum to your enum class and give it a default ResponseCode: `ResponseCodes.DEFAULT.getCode()`;